# KAFKA restart issue : Unable to restart kafka without deleting /tmp/kafka-logs

Tags: apache-kafka

Whenever I try to restart kafka it gives following error. It gets resolved once I delete  /tmp/kafka-logs but it also deletes my topics.
Is there a way to fix it ?

```
     ERROR Error while deleting the clean shutdown file in dir /tmp/kafka-logs (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.setLength(Native Method)
        at kafka.log.AbstractIndex$$anonfun$resize$1.apply$mcZ$sp(AbstractIndex.scala:128)
        at kafka.log.AbstractIndex$$anonfun$resize$1.apply(AbstractIndex.scala:115)
        at kafka.log.AbstractIndex$$anonfun$resize$1.apply(AbstractIndex.scala:115)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:251)
        at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.resize(AbstractIndex.scala:115)
        at kafka.log.AbstractIndex$$anonfun$trimToValidSize$1.apply$mcZ$sp(AbstractIndex.scala:184)
        at kafka.log.AbstractIndex$$anonfun$trimToValidSize$1.apply(AbstractIndex.scala:184)
  kafka.log.LogManager.kafka$log$LogManager$$loadLog(LogManager.scala:265)
        at kafka.log.LogManager$$anonfun$loadLogs$2$$anonfun$11$$anonfun$apply$15$$anonfun$apply$2.apply$mcV$sp(LogManager.scala:345)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$$anon$1.run(CoreUtils.scala:63)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2018-11-02 16:00:07,126] INFO Logs loading complete in 4323 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2018-11-02 16:00:07,134] INFO Starting log cleanup with a period of 300000 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2018-11-02 16:00:07,136] INFO Starting log flusher with a default period of 9223372036854775807 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2018-11-02 16:00:07,388] INFO Awaiting socket connections on 0.0.0.0:9092. (kafka.network.Acceptor)
[2018-11-02 16:00:07,414] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=0] Started 1 acceptor threads (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2018-11-02 16:00:07,430] INFO [ExpirationReaper-0-Produce]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2018-11-02 16:00:07,430] INFO [ExpirationReaper-0-Fetch]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2018-11-02 16:00:07,432] INFO [ExpirationReaper-0-DeleteRecords]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2018-11-02 16:00:07,452] INFO [LogDirFailureHandler]: Starting (kafka.server.ReplicaManager$LogDirFailureHandler)
[2018-11-02 16:00:07,453] INFO [ReplicaManager broker=0] Stopping serving replicas in dir /tmp/kafka-logs (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
[2018-11-02 16:00:07,456] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 0] Removed fetcher for partitions  (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
[2018-11-02 16:00:07,458] INFO [ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager on broker 0] Removed fetcher for partitions  (kafka.server.ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager)
[2018-11-02 16:00:07,461] INFO [ReplicaManager broker=0] Broker 0 stopped fetcher for partitions  and stopped moving logs for partitions  because they are in the failed log directory /tmp/kafka-logs. (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
[2018-11-02 16:00:07,462] INFO Stopping serving logs in dir /tmp/kafka-logs (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2018-11-02 16:00:07,465] ERROR Shutdown broker because all log dirs in /tmp/kafka-logs have failed (kafka.log.LogManager)
```

Is there anything I am missing ?

Comment: What version of Kafka? It would be recommended to not store persistent data in `/tmp` anyway, even though that is the default

Comment: Hi @cricket_007,Thanks for replying. I am using kafka_2.11-2.0.0 

Also, how do we configure the location to store data ?

Comment: Edit the `server.properties` file and look for the `log.dirs` setting

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments the way forward seems to be moving the log location out of `/tmp`.

I also recall seeing somewhere that changing ownership to hadoop.hadoop might help but never tried this myself.